# Multiplayer game that needs info from Game Center for both players

Tags: ios, game-center, multiplayer, autologin

I'm making a pass-and-play multiplayer game. Both players could have info stored in Game Center that I might need to get, like stats/inventory for their character, but also to update their achievements.

This is how I envision it:

1. Player 1 (device owner) logs in to Game Center (if not already logged in) so I can download his player data.
2. Player 2 manually logs in to Game Center so I can download his player data.
3. I logout player 2 and auto-login player 1 again, since it's his device.
4. They play the game... and enjoy it immensely!
5. After the match, I update player 1's data and achievements automatically.
6. I auto-login player 2 and update his data and achievements.
7. I logout player 2 and auto-login player 1 again.

Is the auto-login possible for multiple users? Or would I have to ask them to re-login manually?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to auto login users in Game Center.

iOS 9 has introduced a Guest Player in Game Center, which allows you to make a pass and play game on the same device.

Comment: But, using the Guest Player won't allow player 2 to use his data from Game Center, like stats/inventory and achievements.

Comment: I guess I'll have to force players to manually re-login if player 2 wants to use his saved Game Center data. Oh well...